# Magento 1.7 upgrade causes newsletter static block to stop working

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade, static-block, newsletter

I am sure this is simple but just can't figure it out.

I am trying to switch back to default newsletter signup for magento but am running into some issues.

When I use

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

The signup block displays but nothing is captured to the subscriber list

And if I use

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Nothing displays at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}` will never work because then the template does not know the form action url.

It should work with `{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}`. Try reverting to the default theme. Maybe there is an issue with your custom theme. The `var/log` folder should give you more details if there are errors.